# How many "straight" functors can be constructed from the category of groups to the category of groups with a "distinguished" element?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Consider the category of groups $\mathcal{G}$ with the usual morphisms and the category of groups with a distinguished point $\mathcal{G}_o.$ The objects of  $\mathcal{G}_o$ are ordered pairs $(G,x)$ such that $ x \in G$ and morphisms between $(G_1,x)$ and $(G_2,y)$ are group morphisms $f:G_1 \to G_2$ such that $ f(x)=y.$ Is its true that if a functor $F$ from  $\mathcal{G}$ to $\mathcal{G}_0,$ satisfies $$F(G)=(G,x)\,\ \,\ (straightness)$$  $\forall G \in\mathcal{G}$ then $x$ is the identity element of $G?$

Comment: You are getting downvotes and close votes because your question is unclear and you have given no information about what you have tried. As stated your problem doesn't seem to make sense: what is $x$ in the equation $F(G) = (G, x)$ (which looks nothing like the usual definition of faithfulness)?

Comment: I would suggest using a different word instead of "faithful" since "faithful functor" already has a standard meaning that is completely different.

Comment: Just to be clear: Your condition on $F$ is that for every group $G$, there is some element $x\in G$ such that $F(G) = (G,x)$. Correct? Do you put any restriction on the action of $F$ on morphisms?

Comment: If you mean "faithful" in its standard sense and your equation is meant to mean that underlying group of $F(G)$ is $G$ itself, then no such functor can exist: if you take $G$ to be group with $3$ elements, then it admits a non-trivial automorphism in $\cal G$, but $(G, x)$ has no non-trivial automorphisms in ${\cal G}_0$ for either choice of $x$.

Comment: I just realized I missued the term "faithful". I replaced it by "straight" which in this case means that that underlying group of F(G) is G  itsef. I hope "straight" functor has never been used before.

Comment: @ Alex Krugman No conditions on morphisms are assumed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Let $0$ be a zero group with unique element $e_0 \in 0$.

Then clearly $F(0) = (0, e_0)$.

Now consider an arbitrary group $G$. Then consider the zero map $0_G : 0 \to G$. Let $F(G) = (G, x)$.

Then we see that $F(0_G) : F(0) \to F(G)$. That is, $F(0_G) : (0, e_0) \to (G, x)$.

Therefore, $F(0_G) = 0_G$. Then we see that $0_G(e_0) = e_G = x$.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the swift  answer to my question. Do you suspect the answer would still be "YES" if the trivial groups are removed from the category?

Comment: @MikeCocos It would. Just look at $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 3\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the $F$-image of the zero maps from these groups to $(G, x)$. Then we see that $x \cdot x \cdot x = e_G$ and $x \cdot x = e_G$. So $x = e_G$. You'd have to remove a lot of groups to permit a nontrivial action on objects for a straight functor.